# Pack a multi-module Gradle library into a single module

Tags: gradle, kotlin, multi-module

I've split my `pancakes` Gradle-based library written in Kotlin into multiple modules: `pancakes-core`, `pancakes-addon1`, ..., `pancakes-addonN`. The `addon` ones include the `core` one.

Now, most users shouldn't care and will just want the default configuration with all the dependencies included. But they will have to write boilerplate:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("pancakes:pancakes-core")
    implementation("pancakes:pancakes-addon1")
    ...
    implementation("pancakes:pancakes-addonN")
}
```

This is a no-go for me. I'll probably have to merge all the modules, although I've just spent some time to branch off some replaceable features into their own modules.

Unless! There is a way to write something like the following:

```
project(":pancakes-simple") {
    dependencies {
        autoForwardedApi(":pancakes-core")
        autoForwardedApi(":pancakes-addon1")
        ...
        autoForwardedApi(":pancakes-addonN")
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `api` is not enough.

Comment: In what way is it not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java-library` Gradle plugin is required for `api` dependencies to be forwarded from the current module. So that's how to pack all the modules into a single one:

1. Add `java-library` plugin (and remove `java`) in all modules of the library
2. Create a module like my `:pancakes-simple` that `api`-depends on all the other modules

Comment: Hello @Anton3 , I followed your suggestion and you were right, I achieved to combine 3 of my modules and publish the combined module, to my Mavenlocal repo as one. But as I saw (correct me if I am wrong), I have to install (publish) to my MavenLocal repo (in my case) all other 3 modules in order to be able to use the combined one, successfully as a dependency in another project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible and close to what you supposed it to look like.

Add a separate subproject, say, `:pancakes-simple` and configure its publishing as you did for your normal modules.

Then just add the dependencies that you want it to expose. If you are not using the `java-library` plugin, use the `compile` configuration:

```
project(":pancakes-simple") {
    dependencies {
        compile(":pancakes-core")
        compile(":pancakes-addon1")
        ...
        compile(":pancakes-addonN")
    }
}
```

Unlike `implementation` dependencies, these will be available on the consumer's compile classpath if they add a dependency on the `pancakes-simple` module.

With the `java-library` plugin, `api` dependencies should also work

Comment: Use `api` instead of `compile` since `compile` is deprecated.

Comment: So I should use replace `java` plugin with `java-library`, and everything will work with `api`?